# How to split through a pair of close and open curely braces

Tags: string, tcl

I have a string like:

```
set a "alfa beta gama} {alfa} {gama"
```

I tried to do:

```
set b [split $a "} {"]
```

I expected the result to be a list b with:

```
element 1 = alfa beta gama
element 2 = alfa
element 3 = gama
```

But when I tried this, I am not getting the desired result as tcl is tring to split with " "

Answer (score 5):

The `split` command takes a *set* of characters as its optional second argument (which is expressed as a string for convenience). The options for doing the sort of splitting you're after are really:

1. Use the `textutil::split` package from Tcllib.

   ```
   package require textutil::split

   set pieces [textutil::split::splitx $yourString "***=\} \{"]
   ```
2. Transform the character sequence into a rare character and split on that:

   ```
   set pieces [split [string map [list "\} \{" "\uffff"] $yourString] "\uffff"]
   ```

Comment: Some of those high Unicode characters are never seen in real texts, and so are ideal for split delegates.

Answer (score 1):

If that's your exact case, Why don't you make that a complete list by appending the starting and the ending brace like this

```
set a "alfa beta gama} {alfa} {gama"
set b "\{$a\}"
```

then you can refer to any of those 3 items using `lindex`

Answer (score 0):

since you did

"`set b "\{$a\}`"

the value of variable b is 
"{alfa beta gama} {alfa} {gama}"

now 
`lindex $b 0` = {alfa beta gama}
`lindex $b 1` = {alfa}
`lindex $b 2`= {gama}